# Fixed footer flickering with JQM1.0 and iOS5

Tags: jquery-mobile, ios5, toolbar, fixed

I'm using JQM1.0 and a fixed footer if flickering heavily on iOS5 (Not in iOS4.3 or Android). To see the flickering, click on "Course View" at the following link: http://www.mycoursewalk.com/mobile_course_walk/show/18

Any ideas?

Thanks,

Nick,

Answer (score 0):

Adding a min-height:100% style to my data-role="content" fixed the issue for me.

I was using a fade data-transition, I've not tried the fix with any others.

This was jquery mobile 1.0.1.

Comment: That did not work for me. JQM 1.0.1 reduced the flickering a bit.

Comment: Looks like there are some real improvements to fixed headers/footers in 1.1: http://jquerymobile.com/test/docs/toolbars/bars-fixed.html works really nicely.